# What type of 8-pin ribbon cable connector is this?

Tags: connector

What type of ribbon cable connector is this in the picture below? I would like to order a compatible male end for a converter plug I am designing.

Edit: The pin spacing (as measured with a digital caliper, by averaging the inside and outside measurements of two pins) is approximately 0.1", so I think the Molex KK is correct.

[image: Ribbon Cable Connector]

For the curious, this is from an OWI robotic arm kit.

Comment: Hm, could we get another picture directly facing the metal contacts? If you just want to have a male plug for this type of connector you could try using a standard pin header.

Comment: Please measure the pin spacing for us.  If it is 0.1" spacing, it looks like a Molex KK connector to me.

Comment: Agreeing with markrages, it looks a lot like a KK, which are available in either .100 or .156 inch pitches. But I don't remember KK having the wide reflective surface on the fem. connector, or the two friction bumps  on the header. Whatever it is, this would normally be considered a "discrete wire" connector rather than a ribbon cable connector -- though as you see here it can also be used with ribbon by seperating the wires out before attaching the connector.

Comment: It looks like 2.54mm and a KK type connector to me too. I think most of the Molex ones have the tab on the upper side though. Having a quick look on Farnell seemed to confirm this, though there were some with the tab on the bottom like this [one](http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/mc34625/header-r-a-sq-pin-2-5mm-8way/dp/1697917) from Multicomp. Either way, pretty much any molex shrouded/unshrouded type 2.54mm pitch connector should be able to be used with that socket.

Comment: This is a *connector with no name* (at least it seems like that to me, I have a hard time finding them). For German people, here is a source: http://www.reichelt.de/Platinen-Steckverbinder/0/500/index.html?;ACTION=2;LA=2;GROUPID=5216

Comment: It's not a ribbon connector. It just happens to have a ribbon cable attached.

Comment: That's an unusual type of "ribbon" cable. It is made with individually insulated wires bonded together rather than being molded all at once like most ribbons used with IDC connectors. These kinds of "ribbon" cables are easier to separate into individual wires. Also, Molex KK connectors are also available in 0.156 inch pitch, not just 0.100 inch (2.54 mm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector on the PCB is a **MOLEX KK Series HEADER, SQUARE PIN, 0.1", 8WAY** and the one on the cable is a **MOLEX KK Series CRIMP HOUSING, 0.1", 8WAY**.

So in order to make a compatible male end, you'll need to get a [8-pin crimp housing](http://uk.farnell.com/molex/22-01-2085/crimp-housing-0-1-8way/dp/143130) (The picture from Farnell isn't accurate, as it shows a connector with only 5 pins) and connect the other end of your cable to it with the help of a 8 x [Crimp Contacts](http://uk.farnell.com/molex/08-50-0031/contact-female-30-22awg-crimp/dp/1759550). And on the converter's PCB you'll have to solder an [8-pin Molex Header](http://uk.farnell.com/molex/22-27-2081/header-square-pin-0-1-8way/dp/9731180).

[Here's a video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ae_3fahJFXw) on how to make a Molex KK crimp connector.

Comment: Does any crimp tool work with those, or do you need something special?

Comment: Nothing special; you can even use some pliers

Comment: Great answer, thanks! My eyes were crossing from looking at random connectors in the Digikey catalog and trying to guess…

Comment: Actually, you're better off getting the right crimp tool for the job if you don't want the wire pulling out. A proper crimp works better than a pliers crimp, even if the pliers crimp is soldered post-crimp (which actually creates a strain point where the solder stops; this area is prone to breakage). P.S. The connector section of the online Digi-Key site search is one of the hardest to search things ever. There is little consistency in their keywords.